# regex to find filename where the first 3 letters are ~~~

Tags: regex

I am trying to match only if the file name's first 3 characters are `~` The rest of the characters can be anything but ~

So if a filename starts with more or less than 3 ~ signs, it should not match.

I have this regex:

```
\~{1,3}[^/]*$
```

It  matches `a/b/c/d/~~~abcd.txt` which is expected.

But it also matches `a/b/c/d/~~~~1234.txt`, `a/b/c/d/~~helloworld.txt` so on and so forth.

Comment: It should be: `^~{3}[^~]*$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex for matching your filenames:

```bash
^~{3}[^~]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hHNnpH/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `~{3}`: Match 3 `~`
- `[^~]*`: Match 0 or more non-`~` characters
- `$`: End

Note that this will only match filenames without the path string before filename.

If you want to match both path and filename then use:

```bash
^(?:[^\/]+\/)*~{3}[^~]*$
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/hHNnpH/2)